# How to generate an MD5 hash from a string in JavaScript/Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, hash, md5

How to generate a MD5 hash using Javascript/Node.js? I already have a `fileVideo` string and I need to generate a MD5 hash for the string.

```
var fileVideo = "my string";
string md5 = functionToGenerateMD5hash(fileVideo);
// send md5 here
```

Comment: Here is a stackoverflow example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/768268/how-to-calculate-md5-hash-of-a-file-using-javascript

Comment: Expample of what? I can't find there any examples of how to get md5 hash of file using js.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to calculate md5 hash of a file using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768268/how-to-calculate-md5-hash-of-a-file-using-javascript) ... and strongly Related: [How to generate checksum & convert to 64 bit in Javascript for very large files without overflowing RAM?
](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51987434/514235)

Comment: For anyone reading this on or after 2022, just go to the real answer using a browser standard API: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53490958/

Comment: [verify](https://fe-tool.com/en-us/hash/md5/?inputText=hello) the md5 result

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You could use [crypto-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-js).

I would also recommend using SHA256, rather than MD5.

To install crypto-js via NPM:

```
npm install crypto-js
```

Alternatively you can use a CDN and reference the [JS file](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.0.0/crypto-js.min.js).

Then to display a MD5 and SHA256 hash, you can do the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var md5Hash = CryptoJS.MD5("Test");
    var sha256Hash = CryptoJS.SHA256("Test1");

    console.log(md5Hash.toString());
    console.log(sha256Hash.toString());
</script>
```

Working example located here, [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ur0e3sc7/)

There are also other JS functions that will generate an `MD5` hash, outlined below.

http://www.myersdaily.org/joseph/javascript/md5-text.html

http://pajhome.org.uk/crypt/md5/md5.html

```
function md5cycle(x, k) {
var a = x[0], b = x[1], c = x[2], d = x[3];

a = ff(a, b, c, d, k[0], 7, -680876936);
d = ff(d, a, b, c, k[1], 12, -389564586);
c = ff(c, d, a, b, k[2], 17,  606105819);
b = ff(b, c, d, a, k[3], 22, -1044525330);
a = ff(a, b, c, d, k[4], 7, -176418897);
d = ff(d, a, b, c, k[5], 12,  1200080426);
c = ff(c, d, a, b, k[6], 17, -1473231341);
b = ff(b, c, d, a, k[7], 22, -45705983);
a = ff(a, b, c, d, k[8], 7,  1770035416);
d = ff(d, a, b, c, k[9], 12, -1958414417);
c = ff(c, d, a, b, k[10], 17, -42063);
b = ff(b, c, d, a, k[11], 22, -1990404162);
a = ff(a, b, c, d, k[12], 7,  1804603682);
d = ff(d, a, b, c, k[13], 12, -40341101);
c = ff(c, d, a, b, k[14], 17, -1502002290);
b = ff(b, c, d, a, k[15], 22,  1236535329);

a = gg(a, b, c, d, k[1], 5, -165796510);
d = gg(d, a, b, c, k[6], 9, -1069501632);
c = gg(c, d, a, b, k[11], 14,  643717713);
b = gg(b, c, d, a, k[0], 20, -373897302);
a = gg(a, b, c, d, k[5], 5, -701558691);
d = gg(d, a, b, c, k[10], 9,  38016083);
c = gg(c, d, a, b, k[15], 14, -660478335);
b = gg(b, c, d, a, k[4], 20, -405537848);
a = gg(a, b, c, d, k[9], 5,  568446438);
d = gg(d, a, b, c, k[14], 9, -1019803690);
c = gg(c, d, a, b, k[3], 14, -187363961);
b = gg(b, c, d, a, k[8], 20,  1163531501);
a = gg(a, b, c, d, k[13], 5, -1444681467);
d = gg(d, a, b, c, k[2], 9, -51403784);
c = gg(c, d, a, b, k[7], 14,  1735328473);
b = gg(b, c, d, a, k[12], 20, -1926607734);

a = hh(a, b, c, d, k[5], 4, -378558);
d = hh(d, a, b, c, k[8], 11, -2022574463);
c = hh(c, d, a, b, k[11], 16,  1839030562);
b = hh(b, c, d, a, k[14], 23, -35309556);
a = hh(a, b, c, d, k[1], 4, -1530992060);
d = hh(d, a, b, c, k[4], 11,  1272893353);
c = hh(c, d, a, b, k[7], 16, -155497632);
b = hh(b, c, d, a, k[10], 23, -1094730640);
a = hh(a, b, c, d, k[13], 4,  681279174);
d = hh(d, a, b, c, k[0], 11, -358537222);
c = hh(c, d, a, b, k[3], 16, -722521979);
b = hh(b, c, d, a, k[6], 23,  76029189);
a = hh(a, b, c, d, k[9], 4, -640364487);
d = hh(d, a, b, c, k[12], 11, -421815835);
c = hh(c, d, a, b, k[15], 16,  530742520);
b = hh(b, c, d, a, k[2], 23, -995338651);

a = ii(a, b, c, d, k[0], 6, -198630844);
d = ii(d, a, b, c, k[7], 10,  1126891415);
c = ii(c, d, a, b, k[14], 15, -1416354905);
b = ii(b, c, d, a, k[5], 21, -57434055);
a = ii(a, b, c, d, k[12], 6,  1700485571);
d = ii(d, a, b, c, k[3], 10, -1894986606);
c = ii(c, d, a, b, k[10], 15, -1051523);
b = ii(b, c, d, a, k[1], 21, -2054922799);
a = ii(a, b, c, d, k[8], 6,  1873313359);
d = ii(d, a, b, c, k[15], 10, -30611744);
c = ii(c, d, a, b, k[6], 15, -1560198380);
b = ii(b, c, d, a, k[13], 21,  1309151649);
a = ii(a, b, c, d, k[4], 6, -145523070);
d = ii(d, a, b, c, k[11], 10, -1120210379);
c = ii(c, d, a, b, k[2], 15,  718787259);
b = ii(b, c, d, a, k[9], 21, -343485551);

x[0] = add32(a, x[0]);
x[1] = add32(b, x[1]);
x[2] = add32(c, x[2]);
x[3] = add32(d, x[3]);

}

function cmn(q, a, b, x, s, t) {
a = add32(add32(a, q), add32(x, t));
return add32((a << s) | (a >>> (32 - s)), b);
}

function ff(a, b, c, d, x, s, t) {
return cmn((b & c) | ((~b) & d), a, b, x, s, t);
}

function gg(a, b, c, d, x, s, t) {
return cmn((b & d) | (c & (~d)), a, b, x, s, t);
}

function hh(a, b, c, d, x, s, t) {
return cmn(b ^ c ^ d, a, b, x, s, t);
}

function ii(a, b, c, d, x, s, t) {
return cmn(c ^ (b | (~d)), a, b, x, s, t);
}

function md51(s) {
txt = '';
var n = s.length,
state = [1732584193, -271733879, -1732584194, 271733878], i;
for (i=64; i<=s.length; i+=64) {
md5cycle(state, md5blk(s.substring(i-64, i)));
}
s = s.substring(i-64);
var tail = [0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0];
for (i=0; i<s.length; i++)
tail[i>>2] |= s.charCodeAt(i) << ((i%4) << 3);
tail[i>>2] |= 0x80 << ((i%4) << 3);
if (i > 55) {
md5cycle(state, tail);
for (i=0; i<16; i++) tail[i] = 0;
}
tail[14] = n*8;
md5cycle(state, tail);
return state;
}

/* there needs to be support for Unicode here,
 * unless we pretend that we can redefine the MD-5
 * algorithm for multi-byte characters (perhaps
 * by adding every four 16-bit characters and
 * shortening the sum to 32 bits). Otherwise
 * I suggest performing MD-5 as if every character
 * was two bytes--e.g., 0040 0025 = @%--but then
 * how will an ordinary MD-5 sum be matched?
 * There is no way to standardize text to something
 * like UTF-8 before transformation; speed cost is
 * utterly prohibitive. The JavaScript standard
 * itself needs to look at this: it should start
 * providing access to strings as preformed UTF-8
 * 8-bit unsigned value arrays.
 */
function md5blk(s) { /* I figured global was faster.   */
var md5blks = [], i; /* Andy King said do it this way. */
for (i=0; i<64; i+=4) {
md5blks[i>>2] = s.charCodeAt(i)
+ (s.charCodeAt(i+1) << 8)
+ (s.charCodeAt(i+2) << 16)
+ (s.charCodeAt(i+3) << 24);
}
return md5blks;
}

var hex_chr = '0123456789abcdef'.split('');

function rhex(n)
{
var s='', j=0;
for(; j<4; j++)
s += hex_chr[(n >> (j * 8 + 4)) & 0x0F]
+ hex_chr[(n >> (j * 8)) & 0x0F];
return s;
}

function hex(x) {
for (var i=0; i<x.length; i++)
x[i] = rhex(x[i]);
return x.join('');
}

function md5(s) {
return hex(md51(s));
}

/* this function is much faster,
so if possible we use it. Some IEs
are the only ones I know of that
need the idiotic second function,
generated by an if clause.  */

function add32(a, b) {
return (a + b) & 0xFFFFFFFF;
}

if (md5('hello') != '5d41402abc4b2a76b9719d911017c592') {
function add32(x, y) {
var lsw = (x & 0xFFFF) + (y & 0xFFFF),
msw = (x >> 16) + (y >> 16) + (lsw >> 16);
return (msw << 16) | (lsw & 0xFFFF);
}
}
```

Then simply use the MD5 function, as shown below:

```
alert(md5("Test string"));
```

Another working [JS Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/fo5v2gw1/)

Comment: But these function work with string and i have a ArrayBuffer of big file(video). Also thank for recommendation but i need md5 not for password, just for file hash sum.

Comment: There are times when md5 is fine. For example, if you are trying to limit comment spam, have JS replace the CSRF token with md5sum of CSRF token. Bots that don't have a JS engine won't be able to.

Comment: it might be useful if you address the question asked in the title too, and add how to calculate an md5 hash for a file not necessarily on the file system e.g. a file you have the HTTP URL for

Comment: MD5 is unsecure. https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Guide_to_Cryptography#How_to_determine_if_you_are_vulnerable and 
https://www.bentasker.co.uk/blog/security/201-why-you-should-be-asking-how-your-passwords-are-stored

Comment: @Kiquenet yes, which is why I recommended SHA256 and provided an example.

Comment: Not everything has to be "secure", guys. All the original question seeks to accomplish is to create a unique hash out of a file - why assume security is even a consideration? What if the goal is to simply optimize identification of one file from another... put some of the hashing load on the client. Seems like a perfectly valid use of MD5 to me.

Comment: @jordancpaul - I provided an answer for MD5 and also a secure alternative utilising SHA256. Whilst I answered the OP’s original question with an MD5 example, recommending a more secure solution and also providing an example is good practice. Hopefully it helps future readers of this question. Wether the OP has considered security or not, they can decide for themselves which hashing algorithm is the best solution for their problem based on the examples in the answer.

Answer (score 219):

If you don't want to use libraries or other things, you can use this native javascript approach:

```js
var MD5 = function(d){var r = M(V(Y(X(d),8*d.length)));return r.toLowerCase()};function M(d){for(var _,m="0123456789ABCDEF",f="",r=0;r<d.length;r++)_=d.charCodeAt(r),f+=m.charAt(_>>>4&15)+m.charAt(15&_);return f}function X(d){for(var _=Array(d.length>>2),m=0;m<_.length;m++)_[m]=0;for(m=0;m<8*d.length;m+=8)_[m>>5]|=(255&d.charCodeAt(m/8))<<m%32;return _}function V(d){for(var _="",m=0;m<32*d.length;m+=8)_+=String.fromCharCode(d[m>>5]>>>m%32&255);return _}function Y(d,_){d[_>>5]|=128<<_%32,d[14+(_+64>>>9<<4)]=_;for(var m=1732584193,f=-271733879,r=-1732584194,i=271733878,n=0;n<d.length;n+=16){var h=m,t=f,g=r,e=i;f=md5_ii(f=md5_ii(f=md5_ii(f=md5_ii(f=md5_hh(f=md5_hh(f=md5_hh(f=md5_hh(f=md5_gg(f=md5_gg(f=md5_gg(f=md5_gg(f=md5_ff(f=md5_ff(f=md5_ff(f=md5_ff(f,r=md5_ff(r,i=md5_ff(i,m=md5_ff(m,f,r,i,d[n+0],7,-680876936),f,r,d[n+1],12,-389564586),m,f,d[n+2],17,606105819),i,m,d[n+3],22,-1044525330),r=md5_ff(r,i=md5_ff(i,m=md5_ff(m,f,r,i,d[n+4],7,-176418897),f,r,d[n+5],12,1200080426),m,f,d[n+6],17,-1473231341),i,m,d[n+7],22,-45705983),r=md5_ff(r,i=md5_ff(i,m=md5_ff(m,f,r,i,d[n+8],7,1770035416),f,r,d[n+9],12,-1958414417),m,f,d[n+10],17,-42063),i,m,d[n+11],22,-1990404162),r=md5_ff(r,i=md5_ff(i,m=md5_ff(m,f,r,i,d[n+12],7,1804603682),f,r,d[n+13],12,-40341101),m,f,d[n+14],17,-1502002290),i,m,d[n+15],22,1236535329),r=md5_gg(r,i=md5_gg(i,m=md5_gg(m,f,r,i,d[n+1],5,-165796510),f,r,d[n+6],9,-1069501632),m,f,d[n+11],14,643717713),i,m,d[n+0],20,-373897302),r=md5_gg(r,i=md5_gg(i,m=md5_gg(m,f,r,i,d[n+5],5,-701558691),f,r,d[n+10],9,38016083),m,f,d[n+15],14,-660478335),i,m,d[n+4],20,-405537848),r=md5_gg(r,i=md5_gg(i,m=md5_gg(m,f,r,i,d[n+9],5,568446438),f,r,d[n+14],9,-1019803690),m,f,d[n+3],14,-187363961),i,m,d[n+8],20,1163531501),r=md5_gg(r,i=md5_gg(i,m=md5_gg(m,f,r,i,d[n+13],5,-1444681467),f,r,d[n+2],9,-51403784),m,f,d[n+7],14,1735328473),i,m,d[n+12],20,-1926607734),r=md5_hh(r,i=md5_hh(i,m=md5_hh(m,f,r,i,d[n+5],4,-378558),f,r,d[n+8],11,-2022574463),m,f,d[n+11],16,1839030562),i,m,d[n+14],23,-35309556),r=md5_hh(r,i=md5_hh(i,m=md5_hh(m,f,r,i,d[n+1],4,-1530992060),f,r,d[n+4],11,1272893353),m,f,d[n+7],16,-155497632),i,m,d[n+10],23,-1094730640),r=md5_hh(r,i=md5_hh(i,m=md5_hh(m,f,r,i,d[n+13],4,681279174),f,r,d[n+0],11,-358537222),m,f,d[n+3],16,-722521979),i,m,d[n+6],23,76029189),r=md5_hh(r,i=md5_hh(i,m=md5_hh(m,f,r,i,d[n+9],4,-640364487),f,r,d[n+12],11,-421815835),m,f,d[n+15],16,530742520),i,m,d[n+2],23,-995338651),r=md5_ii(r,i=md5_ii(i,m=md5_ii(m,f,r,i,d[n+0],6,-198630844),f,r,d[n+7],10,1126891415),m,f,d[n+14],15,-1416354905),i,m,d[n+5],21,-57434055),r=md5_ii(r,i=md5_ii(i,m=md5_ii(m,f,r,i,d[n+12],6,1700485571),f,r,d[n+3],10,-1894986606),m,f,d[n+10],15,-1051523),i,m,d[n+1],21,-2054922799),r=md5_ii(r,i=md5_ii(i,m=md5_ii(m,f,r,i,d[n+8],6,1873313359),f,r,d[n+15],10,-30611744),m,f,d[n+6],15,-1560198380),i,m,d[n+13],21,1309151649),r=md5_ii(r,i=md5_ii(i,m=md5_ii(m,f,r,i,d[n+4],6,-145523070),f,r,d[n+11],10,-1120210379),m,f,d[n+2],15,718787259),i,m,d[n+9],21,-343485551),m=safe_add(m,h),f=safe_add(f,t),r=safe_add(r,g),i=safe_add(i,e)}return Array(m,f,r,i)}function md5_cmn(d,_,m,f,r,i){return safe_add(bit_rol(safe_add(safe_add(_,d),safe_add(f,i)),r),m)}function md5_ff(d,_,m,f,r,i,n){return md5_cmn(_&m|~_&f,d,_,r,i,n)}function md5_gg(d,_,m,f,r,i,n){return md5_cmn(_&f|m&~f,d,_,r,i,n)}function md5_hh(d,_,m,f,r,i,n){return md5_cmn(_^m^f,d,_,r,i,n)}function md5_ii(d,_,m,f,r,i,n){return md5_cmn(m^(_|~f),d,_,r,i,n)}function safe_add(d,_){var m=(65535&d)+(65535&_);return(d>>16)+(_>>16)+(m>>16)<<16|65535&m}function bit_rol(d,_){return d<<_|d>>>32-_}

/** NORMAL words**/
var value = 'test';

var result = MD5(value);
 
document.body.innerHTML = 'hash -  normal words: ' + result;

/** NON ENGLISH words**/
value = 'מבחן'

//unescape() can be deprecated for the new browser versions
result = MD5(unescape(encodeURIComponent(value)));

document.body.innerHTML += '<br><br>hash - non english words: ' + result;
```

For non english words you may need to use [unescape()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/unescape) and the [encodeURIComponent()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp) methods.

> ps. Using or allowing old or weak cryptographic algorithms (For example, MD5, SHA1) can allow an attacker to decrypt information with minimal effort.

Comment: Is there any way to do it in incremental way i.e. 100 MB file divided in 100 x 1 MB chunks and then combining their checksums. Also do you have such algo for SHA256? E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/8888429/514235

Comment: Solution for unicode string: `unescape(encodeURIComponent('unicode string'))`

Comment: @mir88 can you share an example?

Comment: why does not take bytearray as input? very weird.

Comment: Where's the `MD5` method referred from, how can we determine its authenticity to ensure it works as expected?

Answer (score 74):

**CryptoJS** is a crypto library which can generate md5 hash among others:

Usage with Script tag:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.0.0/core.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.9-1/md5.js"></script>
<script>
   var hash = CryptoJS.MD5("Message");
   alert(hash);
</script>
```

Alternatively with ES6:

`npm install crypto-js`

```
import MD5 from "crypto-js/md5";
console.log(MD5("Message").toString());
```

You can also use modular imports:

```
var MD5 = require("crypto-js/md5");
console.log(MD5("Message").toString());
```

**Github**: https://github.com/brix/crypto-js 
**CDN**: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/crypto-js

Comment: @RamenChef I'm not affiliated with the library, I found it useful and apparently others do too, from the number of upvotes.

Comment: Not available anymore.

Comment: @VansuitaJr. on what basis are you making that claim?   while the URL he put in the src attribute is broken and needs updating, the links to the project still work. And they link to a crypto-js zip with an md5.js file

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37187554/crypto-js-lib-is-not-available-anymore

Comment: var hash = CryptoJS.MD5("Message").toString();

Answer (score 36):

As a contemporary alternative, there is a standard now for client side cryptography. This has the advantage of being optimised by the browser itself.

Taken from the example in the documentation:

```js
async function sha256(message) {
    // encode as UTF-8
    const msgBuffer = new TextEncoder().encode(message);

    // hash the message
    const hashBuffer = await crypto.subtle.digest('SHA-256', msgBuffer);
    
    // convert ArrayBuffer to Array
    const hashArray = Array.from(new Uint8Array(hashBuffer));

    // convert bytes to hex string
    const hashHex = hashArray.map(b => ('00' + b.toString(16)).slice(-2)).join('');
    return hashHex;
}

sha256('abc').then(hash => console.log(hash));

(async function() {
    const hash = await sha256('abc');
}());
```

MD5 is likely unsupported, however the likes of SHA-256, SHA-384, and SHA-512 are.

And those will likely be able to be calculated server side also.

Here's some documentation on usage: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/digest

And cross browser compatibility: https://caniuse.com/#feat=cryptography

Comment: This is the correct answer now (and md5 is not secure anymore).

Comment: I wanted to use this API so much, but I use virtual hosts (like http://my.project.test/) instead of plain "http://localhost/". It's not considered a secure context, so it doesn't work. Is there a solution for this other than using https on a development system?

Comment: It's possible to create self signed certificates to use locally and thus have https://my.project.test, I'd suggest researching that direction.

Comment: To use the SubtleCrypto api you need to be in a secure context, a domain ending in .localhost is secure for when you don't need https. [MDN Secure_Contexts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Secure_Contexts)

Comment: actually MD5 isn't cryptography, It's a hash, that is VERY different. Hashes ar used in crypto but they aren't cryptographies themselves.

Comment: Very true, it was a long time I posted this, but if I recall I probably said cryptography as it's in the Web Crypto  API.  SHA-2 in itself is a cryptographic hash function.

Answer (score 19):

**2023 update**

This is a popular thread still being hit by searches and most of the top answers are not relevant nowadays.

NodeJS (V8 actually) provides a **native hashing** implementation via **crypto** module.

**Don't** use any own/3rd/2nd party libraries anymore.

**Do**:

- obtain content that you'd like to hash, see below
- create, each time, a hash function
- do the hash

###### Text (simplified example)

```
import { createHash } from 'node:crypto';

function hashText(content, algo = 'md5') {
  const hashFunc = createHash(algo);   // you can also sha256, sha512 etc
  hashFunc.update(content);
  return hashFunc.digest('hex');       // will return hash, formatted to HEX
}
```

###### File (streaming example)

```
import { createHash } from 'node:crypto';
import { createReadStream } from 'node:fs';

async function hashFile(path, algo = 'md5') {
  const hashFunc = createHash(algo);   // you can also sha256, sha512 etc

  const contentStream = createReadStream(path);
  const updateDone = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    contentStream.on('data', (data) => hashFunc.update(data));
    contentStream.on('close', resolve);
    contentStream.on('error', reject);
  });

  await updateDone;
  return hashFunc.digest('hex');       // will return hash, formatted to HEX
}
```

[Relevant documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#class-hash)

Comment: If I have a file buffer in memory, should I use the first (Text) approach?

Comment: @RenanCoelho as per [this doc](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#hashupdatedata-inputencoding) `update` function, which is the relevant part for your question, might take string, buffer, typed array etc, so you should be able to use the first approach passing the buffer in.

Answer (score 10):

Here's a simplified and minified version (about 3.5k) of [this nice implementation](http://pajhome.org.uk/crypt/md5/md5.html):

```
function md5(d){return rstr2hex(binl2rstr(binl_md5(rstr2binl(d),8*d.length)))}function rstr2hex(d){for(var _,m="0123456789ABCDEF",f="",r=0;r<d.length;r++)_=d.charCodeAt(r),f+=m.charAt(_>>>4&15)+m.charAt(15&_);return f}function rstr2binl(d){for(var _=Array(d.length>>2),m=0;m<_.length;m++)_[m]=0;for(m=0;m<8*d.length;m+=8)_[m>>5]|=(255&d.charCodeAt(m/8))<<m%32;return _}function binl2rstr(d){for(var _="",m=0;m<32*d.length;m+=8)_+=String.fromCharCode(d[m>>5]>>>m%32&255);return _}function binl_md5(d,_){d[_>>5]|=128<<_%32,d[14+(_+64>>>9<<4)]=_;for(var m=1732584193,f=-271733879,r=-1732584194,i=271733878,n=0;n<d.length;n+=16){var h=m,t=f,g=r,e=i;f=md5_ii(f=md5_ii(f=md5_ii(f=md5_ii(f=md5_hh(f=md5_hh(f=md5_hh(f=md5_hh(f=md5_gg(f=md5_gg(f=md5_gg(f=md5_gg(f=md5_ff(f=md5_ff(f=md5_ff(f=md5_ff(f,r=md5_ff(r,i=md5_ff(i,m=md5_ff(m,f,r,i,d[n+0],7,-680876936),f,r,d[n+1],12,-389564586),m,f,d[n+2],17,606105819),i,m,d[n+3],22,-1044525330),r=md5_ff(r,i=md5_ff(i,m=md5_ff(m,f,r,i,d[n+4],7,-176418897),f,r,d[n+5],12,1200080426),m,f,d[n+6],17,-1473231341),i,m,d[n+7],22,-45705983),r=md5_ff(r,i=md5_ff(i,m=md5_ff(m,f,r,i,d[n+8],7,1770035416),f,r,d[n+9],12,-1958414417),m,f,d[n+10],17,-42063),i,m,d[n+11],22,-1990404162),r=md5_ff(r,i=md5_ff(i,m=md5_ff(m,f,r,i,d[n+12],7,1804603682),f,r,d[n+13],12,-40341101),m,f,d[n+14],17,-1502002290),i,m,d[n+15],22,1236535329),r=md5_gg(r,i=md5_gg(i,m=md5_gg(m,f,r,i,d[n+1],5,-165796510),f,r,d[n+6],9,-1069501632),m,f,d[n+11],14,643717713),i,m,d[n+0],20,-373897302),r=md5_gg(r,i=md5_gg(i,m=md5_gg(m,f,r,i,d[n+5],5,-701558691),f,r,d[n+10],9,38016083),m,f,d[n+15],14,-660478335),i,m,d[n+4],20,-405537848),r=md5_gg(r,i=md5_gg(i,m=md5_gg(m,f,r,i,d[n+9],5,568446438),f,r,d[n+14],9,-1019803690),m,f,d[n+3],14,-187363961),i,m,d[n+8],20,1163531501),r=md5_gg(r,i=md5_gg(i,m=md5_gg(m,f,r,i,d[n+13],5,-1444681467),f,r,d[n+2],9,-51403784),m,f,d[n+7],14,1735328473),i,m,d[n+12],20,-1926607734),r=md5_hh(r,i=md5_hh(i,m=md5_hh(m,f,r,i,d[n+5],4,-378558),f,r,d[n+8],11,-2022574463),m,f,d[n+11],16,1839030562),i,m,d[n+14],23,-35309556),r=md5_hh(r,i=md5_hh(i,m=md5_hh(m,f,r,i,d[n+1],4,-1530992060),f,r,d[n+4],11,1272893353),m,f,d[n+7],16,-155497632),i,m,d[n+10],23,-1094730640),r=md5_hh(r,i=md5_hh(i,m=md5_hh(m,f,r,i,d[n+13],4,681279174),f,r,d[n+0],11,-358537222),m,f,d[n+3],16,-722521979),i,m,d[n+6],23,76029189),r=md5_hh(r,i=md5_hh(i,m=md5_hh(m,f,r,i,d[n+9],4,-640364487),f,r,d[n+12],11,-421815835),m,f,d[n+15],16,530742520),i,m,d[n+2],23,-995338651),r=md5_ii(r,i=md5_ii(i,m=md5_ii(m,f,r,i,d[n+0],6,-198630844),f,r,d[n+7],10,1126891415),m,f,d[n+14],15,-1416354905),i,m,d[n+5],21,-57434055),r=md5_ii(r,i=md5_ii(i,m=md5_ii(m,f,r,i,d[n+12],6,1700485571),f,r,d[n+3],10,-1894986606),m,f,d[n+10],15,-1051523),i,m,d[n+1],21,-2054922799),r=md5_ii(r,i=md5_ii(i,m=md5_ii(m,f,r,i,d[n+8],6,1873313359),f,r,d[n+15],10,-30611744),m,f,d[n+6],15,-1560198380),i,m,d[n+13],21,1309151649),r=md5_ii(r,i=md5_ii(i,m=md5_ii(m,f,r,i,d[n+4],6,-145523070),f,r,d[n+11],10,-1120210379),m,f,d[n+2],15,718787259),i,m,d[n+9],21,-343485551),m=safe_add(m,h),f=safe_add(f,t),r=safe_add(r,g),i=safe_add(i,e)}return Array(m,f,r,i)}function md5_cmn(d,_,m,f,r,i){return safe_add(bit_rol(safe_add(safe_add(_,d),safe_add(f,i)),r),m)}function md5_ff(d,_,m,f,r,i,n){return md5_cmn(_&m|~_&f,d,_,r,i,n)}function md5_gg(d,_,m,f,r,i,n){return md5_cmn(_&f|m&~f,d,_,r,i,n)}function md5_hh(d,_,m,f,r,i,n){return md5_cmn(_^m^f,d,_,r,i,n)}function md5_ii(d,_,m,f,r,i,n){return md5_cmn(m^(_|~f),d,_,r,i,n)}function safe_add(d,_){var m=(65535&d)+(65535&_);return(d>>16)+(_>>16)+(m>>16)<<16|65535&m}function bit_rol(d,_){return d<<_|d>>>32-_}
```

The function will return an uppercase 32-character string like `098F6BCD4621D373CADE4E832627B4F6`.

For simple alphanumeric strings, you can run it like this:

```
md5('test')
```

If you need full unicode support, you can call [unescape](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/unescape) and [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) on the string before passing it:

```
md5(unescape(encodeURIComponent('')))
```

Comment: For non English texts, this implementation generates wrong hashes

Comment: @OlegGrishko "stripped utf-8 conversion"

Comment: In case you don't want to deal with global namespace pollution and want to encapsulate this code into a [throwaway encapsulated anonymous function expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634268/explain-the-encapsulated-anonymous-function-syntax), add `(function (text) {` before and `;return md5(text);})('YOUR TEXT')` after that block of code.

Answer (score 4):

Added Unicode support to [@valdeci](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4157589/valdeci) and [@Derzu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1178478/derzu) versions.
It can be used to md5-ize JSON objects too.
Added incompatibility with IE11 and below :)

```
var md5 = (function() {
    var MD5 = function (d) {
        return M(V(Y(X(d), 8 * d.length)))
    }
    function M (d) {
        for (var _, m = '0123456789abcdef', f = '', r = 0; r < d.length; r++) {
            _ = d.charCodeAt(r)
            f += m.charAt(_ >>> 4 & 15) + m.charAt(15 & _)
        }
        return f
    }
    function X (d) {
        for (var _ = Array(d.length >> 2), m = 0; m < _.length; m++) {
            _[m] = 0
        }
        for (m = 0; m < 8 * d.length; m += 8) {
            _[m >> 5] |= (255 & d.charCodeAt(m / 8)) << m % 32
        }
        return _
    }
    function V (d) {
        for (var _ = '', m = 0; m < 32 * d.length; m += 8) _ += String.fromCharCode(d[m >> 5] >>> m % 32 & 255)
        return _
    }
    function Y (d, _) {
        d[_ >> 5] |= 128 << _ % 32
        d[14 + (_ + 64 >>> 9 << 4)] = _
        for (var m = 1732584193, f = -271733879, r = -1732584194, i = 271733878, n = 0; n < d.length; n += 16) {
            var h = m
            var t = f
            var g = r
            var e = i
            f = md5ii(f = md5ii(f = md5ii(f = md5ii(f = md5hh(f = md5hh(f = md5hh(f = md5hh(f = md5gg(f = md5gg(f = md5gg(f = md5gg(f = md5ff(f = md5ff(f = md5ff(f = md5ff(f, r = md5ff(r, i = md5ff(i, m = md5ff(m, f, r, i, d[n + 0], 7, -680876936), f, r, d[n + 1], 12, -389564586), m, f, d[n + 2], 17, 606105819), i, m, d[n + 3], 22, -1044525330), r = md5ff(r, i = md5ff(i, m = md5ff(m, f, r, i, d[n + 4], 7, -176418897), f, r, d[n + 5], 12, 1200080426), m, f, d[n + 6], 17, -1473231341), i, m, d[n + 7], 22, -45705983), r = md5ff(r, i = md5ff(i, m = md5ff(m, f, r, i, d[n + 8], 7, 1770035416), f, r, d[n + 9], 12, -1958414417), m, f, d[n + 10], 17, -42063), i, m, d[n + 11], 22, -1990404162), r = md5ff(r, i = md5ff(i, m = md5ff(m, f, r, i, d[n + 12], 7, 1804603682), f, r, d[n + 13], 12, -40341101), m, f, d[n + 14], 17, -1502002290), i, m, d[n + 15], 22, 1236535329), r = md5gg(r, i = md5gg(i, m = md5gg(m, f, r, i, d[n + 1], 5, -165796510), f, r, d[n + 6], 9, -1069501632), m, f, d[n + 11], 14, 643717713), i, m, d[n + 0], 20, -373897302), r = md5gg(r, i = md5gg(i, m = md5gg(m, f, r, i, d[n + 5], 5, -701558691), f, r, d[n + 10], 9, 38016083), m, f, d[n + 15], 14, -660478335), i, m, d[n + 4], 20, -405537848), r = md5gg(r, i = md5gg(i, m = md5gg(m, f, r, i, d[n + 9], 5, 568446438), f, r, d[n + 14], 9, -1019803690), m, f, d[n + 3], 14, -187363961), i, m, d[n + 8], 20, 1163531501), r = md5gg(r, i = md5gg(i, m = md5gg(m, f, r, i, d[n + 13], 5, -1444681467), f, r, d[n + 2], 9, -51403784), m, f, d[n + 7], 14, 1735328473), i, m, d[n + 12], 20, -1926607734), r = md5hh(r, i = md5hh(i, m = md5hh(m, f, r, i, d[n + 5], 4, -378558), f, r, d[n + 8], 11, -2022574463), m, f, d[n + 11], 16, 1839030562), i, m, d[n + 14], 23, -35309556), r = md5hh(r, i = md5hh(i, m = md5hh(m, f, r, i, d[n + 1], 4, -1530992060), f, r, d[n + 4], 11, 1272893353), m, f, d[n + 7], 16, -155497632), i, m, d[n + 10], 23, -1094730640), r = md5hh(r, i = md5hh(i, m = md5hh(m, f, r, i, d[n + 13], 4, 681279174), f, r, d[n + 0], 11, -358537222), m, f, d[n + 3], 16, -722521979), i, m, d[n + 6], 23, 76029189), r = md5hh(r, i = md5hh(i, m = md5hh(m, f, r, i, d[n + 9], 4, -640364487), f, r, d[n + 12], 11, -421815835), m, f, d[n + 15], 16, 530742520), i, m, d[n + 2], 23, -995338651), r = md5ii(r, i = md5ii(i, m = md5ii(m, f, r, i, d[n + 0], 6, -198630844), f, r, d[n + 7], 10, 1126891415), m, f, d[n + 14], 15, -1416354905), i, m, d[n + 5], 21, -57434055), r = md5ii(r, i = md5ii(i, m = md5ii(m, f, r, i, d[n + 12], 6, 1700485571), f, r, d[n + 3], 10, -1894986606), m, f, d[n + 10], 15, -1051523), i, m, d[n + 1], 21, -2054922799), r = md5ii(r, i = md5ii(i, m = md5ii(m, f, r, i, d[n + 8], 6, 1873313359), f, r, d[n + 15], 10, -30611744), m, f, d[n + 6], 15, -1560198380), i, m, d[n + 13], 21, 1309151649), r = md5ii(r, i = md5ii(i, m = md5ii(m, f, r, i, d[n + 4], 6, -145523070), f, r, d[n + 11], 10, -1120210379), m, f, d[n + 2], 15, 718787259), i, m, d[n + 9], 21, -343485551)
            m = safeadd(m, h)
            f = safeadd(f, t)
            r = safeadd(r, g)
            i = safeadd(i, e)
        }
        return [m, f, r, i]
    }
    function md5cmn (d, _, m, f, r, i) {
        return safeadd(bitrol(safeadd(safeadd(_, d), safeadd(f, i)), r), m)
    }
    function md5ff (d, _, m, f, r, i, n) {
        return md5cmn(_ & m | ~_ & f, d, _, r, i, n)
    }
    function md5gg (d, _, m, f, r, i, n) {
        return md5cmn(_ & f | m & ~f, d, _, r, i, n)
    }
    function md5hh (d, _, m, f, r, i, n) {
        return md5cmn(_ ^ m ^ f, d, _, r, i, n)
    }
    function md5ii (d, _, m, f, r, i, n) {
        return md5cmn(m ^ (_ | ~f), d, _, r, i, n)
    }
    function safeadd (d, _) {
        var m = (65535 & d) + (65535 & _)
        return (d >> 16) + (_ >> 16) + (m >> 16) << 16 | 65535 & m
    }
    function bitrol (d, _) {
        return d << _ | d >>> 32 - _
    }
    function MD5Unicode(buffer){
        if (!(buffer instanceof Uint8Array)) {
            buffer = new TextEncoder().encode(typeof buffer==='string' ? buffer : JSON.stringify(buffer));
        }
        var binary = [];
        var bytes = new Uint8Array(buffer);
        for (var i = 0, il = bytes.byteLength; i < il; i++) {
            binary.push(String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]));
        }
        return MD5(binary.join(''));
    }
    
    return MD5Unicode;
})();

md5('òàùèéì€'); // aeb60a568b5bf37d397dde71dacf5519
md5({ prop1: 'òàùèéì€', prop2: 123 }); // 4334a47d3304a628e5b376bce203adbe
```

Comment: I can confirm that this works using a modern create-react-app and want to integrate with Gravatar.  Thanks for this, now I don't need a library!

Answer (score 3):

This is a JSLint compatible version of @valdeci 's answer.

```js
var MD5 = function (d) {
    return M(V(Y(X(d), 8 * d.length)))
}
function M (d) {
    for (var _, m = '0123456789ABCDEF', f = '', r = 0; r < d.length; r++) {
        _ = d.charCodeAt(r)
        f += m.charAt(_ >>> 4 & 15) + m.charAt(15 & _)
    }
    return f
}
function X (d) {
    for (var _ = Array(d.length >> 2), m = 0; m < _.length; m++) {
        _[m] = 0
    }
    for (m = 0; m < 8 * d.length; m += 8) {
        _[m >> 5] |= (255 & d.charCodeAt(m / 8)) << m % 32
    }
    return _
}
function V (d) {
    for (var _ = '', m = 0; m < 32 * d.length; m += 8) _ += String.fromCharCode(d[m >> 5] >>> m % 32 & 255)
    return _
}
function Y (d, _) {
    d[_ >> 5] |= 128 << _ % 32
    d[14 + (_ + 64 >>> 9 << 4)] = _
    for (var m = 1732584193, f = -271733879, r = -1732584194, i = 271733878, n = 0; n < d.length; n += 16) {
        var h = m
        var t = f
        var g = r
        var e = i
        f = md5ii(f = md5ii(f = md5ii(f = md5ii(f = md5hh(f = md5hh(f = md5hh(f = md5hh(f = md5gg(f = md5gg(f = md5gg(f = md5gg(f = md5ff(f = md5ff(f = md5ff(f = md5ff(f, r = md5ff(r, i = md5ff(i, m = md5ff(m, f, r, i, d[n + 0], 7, -680876936), f, r, d[n + 1], 12, -389564586), m, f, d[n + 2], 17, 606105819), i, m, d[n + 3], 22, -1044525330), r = md5ff(r, i = md5ff(i, m = md5ff(m, f, r, i, d[n + 4], 7, -176418897), f, r, d[n + 5], 12, 1200080426), m, f, d[n + 6], 17, -1473231341), i, m, d[n + 7], 22, -45705983), r = md5ff(r, i = md5ff(i, m = md5ff(m, f, r, i, d[n + 8], 7, 1770035416), f, r, d[n + 9], 12, -1958414417), m, f, d[n + 10], 17, -42063), i, m, d[n + 11], 22, -1990404162), r = md5ff(r, i = md5ff(i, m = md5ff(m, f, r, i, d[n + 12], 7, 1804603682), f, r, d[n + 13], 12, -40341101), m, f, d[n + 14], 17, -1502002290), i, m, d[n + 15], 22, 1236535329), r = md5gg(r, i = md5gg(i, m = md5gg(m, f, r, i, d[n + 1], 5, -165796510), f, r, d[n + 6], 9, -1069501632), m, f, d[n + 11], 14, 643717713), i, m, d[n + 0], 20, -373897302), r = md5gg(r, i = md5gg(i, m = md5gg(m, f, r, i, d[n + 5], 5, -701558691), f, r, d[n + 10], 9, 38016083), m, f, d[n + 15], 14, -660478335), i, m, d[n + 4], 20, -405537848), r = md5gg(r, i = md5gg(i, m = md5gg(m, f, r, i, d[n + 9], 5, 568446438), f, r, d[n + 14], 9, -1019803690), m, f, d[n + 3], 14, -187363961), i, m, d[n + 8], 20, 1163531501), r = md5gg(r, i = md5gg(i, m = md5gg(m, f, r, i, d[n + 13], 5, -1444681467), f, r, d[n + 2], 9, -51403784), m, f, d[n + 7], 14, 1735328473), i, m, d[n + 12], 20, -1926607734), r = md5hh(r, i = md5hh(i, m = md5hh(m, f, r, i, d[n + 5], 4, -378558), f, r, d[n + 8], 11, -2022574463), m, f, d[n + 11], 16, 1839030562), i, m, d[n + 14], 23, -35309556), r = md5hh(r, i = md5hh(i, m = md5hh(m, f, r, i, d[n + 1], 4, -1530992060), f, r, d[n + 4], 11, 1272893353), m, f, d[n + 7], 16, -155497632), i, m, d[n + 10], 23, -1094730640), r = md5hh(r, i = md5hh(i, m = md5hh(m, f, r, i, d[n + 13], 4, 681279174), f, r, d[n + 0], 11, -358537222), m, f, d[n + 3], 16, -722521979), i, m, d[n + 6], 23, 76029189), r = md5hh(r, i = md5hh(i, m = md5hh(m, f, r, i, d[n + 9], 4, -640364487), f, r, d[n + 12], 11, -421815835), m, f, d[n + 15], 16, 530742520), i, m, d[n + 2], 23, -995338651), r = md5ii(r, i = md5ii(i, m = md5ii(m, f, r, i, d[n + 0], 6, -198630844), f, r, d[n + 7], 10, 1126891415), m, f, d[n + 14], 15, -1416354905), i, m, d[n + 5], 21, -57434055), r = md5ii(r, i = md5ii(i, m = md5ii(m, f, r, i, d[n + 12], 6, 1700485571), f, r, d[n + 3], 10, -1894986606), m, f, d[n + 10], 15, -1051523), i, m, d[n + 1], 21, -2054922799), r = md5ii(r, i = md5ii(i, m = md5ii(m, f, r, i, d[n + 8], 6, 1873313359), f, r, d[n + 15], 10, -30611744), m, f, d[n + 6], 15, -1560198380), i, m, d[n + 13], 21, 1309151649), r = md5ii(r, i = md5ii(i, m = md5ii(m, f, r, i, d[n + 4], 6, -145523070), f, r, d[n + 11], 10, -1120210379), m, f, d[n + 2], 15, 718787259), i, m, d[n + 9], 21, -343485551)
        m = safeadd(m, h)
        f = safeadd(f, t)
        r = safeadd(r, g)
        i = safeadd(i, e)
    }
    return [m, f, r, i]
}
function md5cmn (d, _, m, f, r, i) {
    return safeadd(bitrol(safeadd(safeadd(_, d), safeadd(f, i)), r), m)
}
function md5ff (d, _, m, f, r, i, n) {
    return md5cmn(_ & m | ~_ & f, d, _, r, i, n)
}
function md5gg (d, _, m, f, r, i, n) {
    return md5cmn(_ & f | m & ~f, d, _, r, i, n)
}
function md5hh (d, _, m, f, r, i, n) {
    return md5cmn(_ ^ m ^ f, d, _, r, i, n)
}
function md5ii (d, _, m, f, r, i, n) {
    return md5cmn(m ^ (_ | ~f), d, _, r, i, n)
}
function safeadd (d, _) {
    var m = (65535 & d) + (65535 & _)
    return (d >> 16) + (_ >> 16) + (m >> 16) << 16 | 65535 & m
}
function bitrol (d, _) {
    return d << _ | d >>> 32 - _
}

var value = 'test';

var result = MD5(value);
 
document.body.innerHTML = 'MD5: ' + result;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const crypto = require('crypto')

var filename = './file.ext'
md5Sum = crypto.createHash('md5')
s = fs.createReadStream(filename)
s.on('data', function(chunk) {
    md5Sum.update(chunk)
    })
s.on('end', function() {
    console.log(md5Sum.digest('hex') + '  ' + filename)
    })
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

it can be found as function on this gist
https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-MD5/blob/master/js/md5.js

```
    /*
 * JavaScript MD5
 * https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-MD5
 *
 * Copyright 2011, Sebastian Tschan
 * https://blueimp.net
 *
 * Licensed under the MIT license:
 * https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT
 *
 * Based on
 * A JavaScript implementation of the RSA Data Security, Inc. MD5 Message
 * Digest Algorithm, as defined in RFC 1321.
 * Version 2.2 Copyright (C) Paul Johnston 1999 - 2009
 * Other contributors: Greg Holt, Andrew Kepert, Ydnar, Lostinet
 * Distributed under the BSD License
 * See http://pajhome.org.uk/crypt/md5 for more info.
 */

/* global define */

/* eslint-disable strict */

;(function ($) {
  'use strict'

  /**
   * Add integers, wrapping at 2^32.
   * This uses 16-bit operations internally to work around bugs in interpreters.
   *
   * @param {number} x First integer
   * @param {number} y Second integer
   * @returns {number} Sum
   */
  function safeAdd(x, y) {
    var lsw = (x & 0xffff) + (y & 0xffff)
    var msw = (x >> 16) + (y >> 16) + (lsw >> 16)
    return (msw << 16) | (lsw & 0xffff)
  }

  /**
   * Bitwise rotate a 32-bit number to the left.
   *
   * @param {number} num 32-bit number
   * @param {number} cnt Rotation count
   * @returns {number} Rotated number
   */
  function bitRotateLeft(num, cnt) {
    return (num << cnt) | (num >>> (32 - cnt))
  }

  /**
   * Basic operation the algorithm uses.
   *
   * @param {number} q q
   * @param {number} a a
   * @param {number} b b
   * @param {number} x x
   * @param {number} s s
   * @param {number} t t
   * @returns {number} Result
   */
  function md5cmn(q, a, b, x, s, t) {
    return safeAdd(bitRotateLeft(safeAdd(safeAdd(a, q), safeAdd(x, t)), s), b)
  }
  /**
   * Basic operation the algorithm uses.
   *
   * @param {number} a a
   * @param {number} b b
   * @param {number} c c
   * @param {number} d d
   * @param {number} x x
   * @param {number} s s
   * @param {number} t t
   * @returns {number} Result
   */
  function md5ff(a, b, c, d, x, s, t) {
    return md5cmn((b & c) | (~b & d), a, b, x, s, t)
  }
  /**
   * Basic operation the algorithm uses.
   *
   * @param {number} a a
   * @param {number} b b
   * @param {number} c c
   * @param {number} d d
   * @param {number} x x
   * @param {number} s s
   * @param {number} t t
   * @returns {number} Result
   */
  function md5gg(a, b, c, d, x, s, t) {
    return md5cmn((b & d) | (c & ~d), a, b, x, s, t)
  }
  /**
   * Basic operation the algorithm uses.
   *
   * @param {number} a a
   * @param {number} b b
   * @param {number} c c
   * @param {number} d d
   * @param {number} x x
   * @param {number} s s
   * @param {number} t t
   * @returns {number} Result
   */
  function md5hh(a, b, c, d, x, s, t) {
    return md5cmn(b ^ c ^ d, a, b, x, s, t)
  }
  /**
   * Basic operation the algorithm uses.
   *
   * @param {number} a a
   * @param {number} b b
   * @param {number} c c
   * @param {number} d d
   * @param {number} x x
   * @param {number} s s
   * @param {number} t t
   * @returns {number} Result
   */
  function md5ii(a, b, c, d, x, s, t) {
    return md5cmn(c ^ (b | ~d), a, b, x, s, t)
  }

  /**
   * Calculate the MD5 of an array of little-endian words, and a bit length.
   *
   * @param {Array} x Array of little-endian words
   * @param {number} len Bit length
   * @returns {Array<number>} MD5 Array
   */
  function binlMD5(x, len) {
    /* append padding */
    x[len >> 5] |= 0x80 << len % 32
    x[(((len + 64) >>> 9) << 4) + 14] = len

    var i
    var olda
    var oldb
    var oldc
    var oldd
    var a = 1732584193
    var b = -271733879
    var c = -1732584194
    var d = 271733878

    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i += 16) {
      olda = a
      oldb = b
      oldc = c
      oldd = d

      a = md5ff(a, b, c, d, x[i], 7, -680876936)
      d = md5ff(d, a, b, c, x[i + 1], 12, -389564586)
      c = md5ff(c, d, a, b, x[i + 2], 17, 606105819)
      b = md5ff(b, c, d, a, x[i + 3], 22, -1044525330)
      a = md5ff(a, b, c, d, x[i + 4], 7, -176418897)
      d = md5ff(d, a, b, c, x[i + 5], 12, 1200080426)
      c = md5ff(c, d, a, b, x[i + 6], 17, -1473231341)
      b = md5ff(b, c, d, a, x[i + 7], 22, -45705983)
      a = md5ff(a, b, c, d, x[i + 8], 7, 1770035416)
      d = md5ff(d, a, b, c, x[i + 9], 12, -1958414417)
      c = md5ff(c, d, a, b, x[i + 10], 17, -42063)
      b = md5ff(b, c, d, a, x[i + 11], 22, -1990404162)
      a = md5ff(a, b, c, d, x[i + 12], 7, 1804603682)
      d = md5ff(d, a, b, c, x[i + 13], 12, -40341101)
      c = md5ff(c, d, a, b, x[i + 14], 17, -1502002290)
      b = md5ff(b, c, d, a, x[i + 15], 22, 1236535329)

      a = md5gg(a, b, c, d, x[i + 1], 5, -165796510)
      d = md5gg(d, a, b, c, x[i + 6], 9, -1069501632)
      c = md5gg(c, d, a, b, x[i + 11], 14, 643717713)
      b = md5gg(b, c, d, a, x[i], 20, -373897302)
      a = md5gg(a, b, c, d, x[i + 5], 5, -701558691)
      d = md5gg(d, a, b, c, x[i + 10], 9, 38016083)
      c = md5gg(c, d, a, b, x[i + 15], 14, -660478335)
      b = md5gg(b, c, d, a, x[i + 4], 20, -405537848)
      a = md5gg(a, b, c, d, x[i + 9], 5, 568446438)
      d = md5gg(d, a, b, c, x[i + 14], 9, -1019803690)
      c = md5gg(c, d, a, b, x[i + 3], 14, -187363961)
      b = md5gg(b, c, d, a, x[i + 8], 20, 1163531501)
      a = md5gg(a, b, c, d, x[i + 13], 5, -1444681467)
      d = md5gg(d, a, b, c, x[i + 2], 9, -51403784)
      c = md5gg(c, d, a, b, x[i + 7], 14, 1735328473)
      b = md5gg(b, c, d, a, x[i + 12], 20, -1926607734)

      a = md5hh(a, b, c, d, x[i + 5], 4, -378558)
      d = md5hh(d, a, b, c, x[i + 8], 11, -2022574463)
      c = md5hh(c, d, a, b, x[i + 11], 16, 1839030562)
      b = md5hh(b, c, d, a, x[i + 14], 23, -35309556)
      a = md5hh(a, b, c, d, x[i + 1], 4, -1530992060)
      d = md5hh(d, a, b, c, x[i + 4], 11, 1272893353)
      c = md5hh(c, d, a, b, x[i + 7], 16, -155497632)
      b = md5hh(b, c, d, a, x[i + 10], 23, -1094730640)
      a = md5hh(a, b, c, d, x[i + 13], 4, 681279174)
      d = md5hh(d, a, b, c, x[i], 11, -358537222)
      c = md5hh(c, d, a, b, x[i + 3], 16, -722521979)
      b = md5hh(b, c, d, a, x[i + 6], 23, 76029189)
      a = md5hh(a, b, c, d, x[i + 9], 4, -640364487)
      d = md5hh(d, a, b, c, x[i + 12], 11, -421815835)
      c = md5hh(c, d, a, b, x[i + 15], 16, 530742520)
      b = md5hh(b, c, d, a, x[i + 2], 23, -995338651)

      a = md5ii(a, b, c, d, x[i], 6, -198630844)
      d = md5ii(d, a, b, c, x[i + 7], 10, 1126891415)
      c = md5ii(c, d, a, b, x[i + 14], 15, -1416354905)
      b = md5ii(b, c, d, a, x[i + 5], 21, -57434055)
      a = md5ii(a, b, c, d, x[i + 12], 6, 1700485571)
      d = md5ii(d, a, b, c, x[i + 3], 10, -1894986606)
      c = md5ii(c, d, a, b, x[i + 10], 15, -1051523)
      b = md5ii(b, c, d, a, x[i + 1], 21, -2054922799)
      a = md5ii(a, b, c, d, x[i + 8], 6, 1873313359)
      d = md5ii(d, a, b, c, x[i + 15], 10, -30611744)
      c = md5ii(c, d, a, b, x[i + 6], 15, -1560198380)
      b = md5ii(b, c, d, a, x[i + 13], 21, 1309151649)
      a = md5ii(a, b, c, d, x[i + 4], 6, -145523070)
      d = md5ii(d, a, b, c, x[i + 11], 10, -1120210379)
      c = md5ii(c, d, a, b, x[i + 2], 15, 718787259)
      b = md5ii(b, c, d, a, x[i + 9], 21, -343485551)

      a = safeAdd(a, olda)
      b = safeAdd(b, oldb)
      c = safeAdd(c, oldc)
      d = safeAdd(d, oldd)
    }
    return [a, b, c, d]
  }

  /**
   * Convert an array of little-endian words to a string
   *
   * @param {Array<number>} input MD5 Array
   * @returns {string} MD5 string
   */
  function binl2rstr(input) {
    var i
    var output = ''
    var length32 = input.length * 32
    for (i = 0; i < length32; i += 8) {
      output += String.fromCharCode((input[i >> 5] >>> i % 32) & 0xff)
    }
    return output
  }

  /**
   * Convert a raw string to an array of little-endian words
   * Characters >255 have their high-byte silently ignored.
   *
   * @param {string} input Raw input string
   * @returns {Array<number>} Array of little-endian words
   */
  function rstr2binl(input) {
    var i
    var output = []
    output[(input.length >> 2) - 1] = undefined
    for (i = 0; i < output.length; i += 1) {
      output[i] = 0
    }
    var length8 = input.length * 8
    for (i = 0; i < length8; i += 8) {
      output[i >> 5] |= (input.charCodeAt(i / 8) & 0xff) << i % 32
    }
    return output
  }

  /**
   * Calculate the MD5 of a raw string
   *
   * @param {string} s Input string
   * @returns {string} Raw MD5 string
   */
  function rstrMD5(s) {
    return binl2rstr(binlMD5(rstr2binl(s), s.length * 8))
  }

  /**
   * Calculates the HMAC-MD5 of a key and some data (raw strings)
   *
   * @param {string} key HMAC key
   * @param {string} data Raw input string
   * @returns {string} Raw MD5 string
   */
  function rstrHMACMD5(key, data) {
    var i
    var bkey = rstr2binl(key)
    var ipad = []
    var opad = []
    var hash
    ipad[15] = opad[15] = undefined
    if (bkey.length > 16) {
      bkey = binlMD5(bkey, key.length * 8)
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 16; i += 1) {
      ipad[i] = bkey[i] ^ 0x36363636
      opad[i] = bkey[i] ^ 0x5c5c5c5c
    }
    hash = binlMD5(ipad.concat(rstr2binl(data)), 512 + data.length * 8)
    return binl2rstr(binlMD5(opad.concat(hash), 512 + 128))
  }

  /**
   * Convert a raw string to a hex string
   *
   * @param {string} input Raw input string
   * @returns {string} Hex encoded string
   */
  function rstr2hex(input) {
    var hexTab = '0123456789abcdef'
    var output = ''
    var x
    var i
    for (i = 0; i < input.length; i += 1) {
      x = input.charCodeAt(i)
      output += hexTab.charAt((x >>> 4) & 0x0f) + hexTab.charAt(x & 0x0f)
    }
    return output
  }

  /**
   * Encode a string as UTF-8
   *
   * @param {string} input Input string
   * @returns {string} UTF8 string
   */
  function str2rstrUTF8(input) {
    return unescape(encodeURIComponent(input))
  }

  /**
   * Encodes input string as raw MD5 string
   *
   * @param {string} s Input string
   * @returns {string} Raw MD5 string
   */
  function rawMD5(s) {
    return rstrMD5(str2rstrUTF8(s))
  }
  /**
   * Encodes input string as Hex encoded string
   *
   * @param {string} s Input string
   * @returns {string} Hex encoded string
   */
  function hexMD5(s) {
    return rstr2hex(rawMD5(s))
  }
  /**
   * Calculates the raw HMAC-MD5 for the given key and data
   *
   * @param {string} k HMAC key
   * @param {string} d Input string
   * @returns {string} Raw MD5 string
   */
  function rawHMACMD5(k, d) {
    return rstrHMACMD5(str2rstrUTF8(k), str2rstrUTF8(d))
  }
  /**
   * Calculates the Hex encoded HMAC-MD5 for the given key and data
   *
   * @param {string} k HMAC key
   * @param {string} d Input string
   * @returns {string} Raw MD5 string
   */
  function hexHMACMD5(k, d) {
    return rstr2hex(rawHMACMD5(k, d))
  }

  /**
   * Calculates MD5 value for a given string.
   * If a key is provided, calculates the HMAC-MD5 value.
   * Returns a Hex encoded string unless the raw argument is given.
   *
   * @param {string} string Input string
   * @param {string} [key] HMAC key
   * @param {boolean} [raw] Raw output switch
   * @returns {string} MD5 output
   */
  function md5(string, key, raw) {
    if (!key) {
      if (!raw) {
        return hexMD5(string)
      }
      return rawMD5(string)
    }
    if (!raw) {
      return hexHMACMD5(key, string)
    }
    return rawHMACMD5(key, string)
  }

  if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    define(function () {
      return md5
    })
  } else if (typeof module === 'object' && module.exports) {
    module.exports = md5
  } else {
    $.md5 = md5
  }
})(this)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a lightweight library [pure-md5](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pure-md5).
Just a 4.7kb.

```js
$("#file-dialog").change(function() {
  handleFiles(this.files);
});

function handleFiles(files) {
  for (var index = 0; index < files.length; index++) {
    var file = files[index];
    var fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = function(e) {
      $('body').append(`
        <div style="margin-top: 2rem;">
          <span>${file.name}: </span>
          <span>${(md5(e.target.result))}</span>
        </div>
      `);
    }

    fileReader.readAsText(file, 'utf-8');
  }

}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/pure-md5@0.1.9/lib/index.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="file-dialog" multiple="true" accept="image/*">
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use crypto-js.

To use crypto-js, you need to load core.js then md5.js .

A list of URLs are here https://cdnjs.com/libraries/crypto-js

cryptojs is also available in zip form here https://code.google.com/archive/p/crypto-js/downloads

There is an answer from answerer 'amal' in 2013, that is similar to this but a)his link to md5.js no longer works b)he didn't load core.js beforehand, which is necessary.

```
<html>    
  <head> 

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.2/components/core.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.2/rollups/md5.js"></script>

  <script>
     var hash = CryptoJS.MD5("Message");
     console.log(hash);
  </script>

  </head>
  <body>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I should really include the code that gets the file..I have it somewhere I plan to add it.    Also, bear in mind that even then it could only get the file returned from the http request which is often a cached file. (though in some web browsers you can tell them to disable cache.. in chrome a simple tick of a box in the inspector, though of course most users won't have that ticked)