# MD5 hash of a file using javascript

Tags: javascript, file-upload, md5

I have to upload a file from the front end and calculate the md5 hash of the file.
I tried to use crypto.js to generate the md5 but for images it is giving me wrong md5.
I saw a website called onlinemd5.com and it is exactly what I need.

Can anyone help me how to calculate the md5 hash of a file(text file, images, videos etc) using javascript?
Is it possible to download the code from http://onlinemd5.com and implement it?

Note: I tried some of the suggestions in [How to calculate md5 hash of a file using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768268/how-to-calculate-md5-hash-of-a-file-using-javascript) but of no use.

---

```
$scope.upld = function(element){
    $scope.files = element.files;
    var file = $scope.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(){
        $scope.md5_val = CryptoJS.MD5(reader.result);
        $scope.upload_file();
        $scope.$apply();
    };
    reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
};
```

The crypto.js is not calculating the image md5 correctly. I did not try the sparkmd5 js though.

Comment: Please describe what exactly you tried and *how* it didn't work. For example: First I ran *a*, but it threw errors, so I tried *b* instead but the result was *c*, which I didn't expect because I was looking for a pattern like *d*.

Comment: Please elaborate on the "but of no use."...

Comment: I am sorry I should have posted the code with my question. Please find it below

Comment: I tried to use the js at  http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-md5.html and uploaded an image file called koala.jpg from the Pictures folder. It calculates the md5 as  '4f413976a7a4b93d19c06e94fae0899d' where as I get a different hash value from onlinemd5.com

Comment: I tried to use the js at - github.com/sagens42/md5asm.                                     It gives me empty string for md5 value. Here's the code:                                                          var calcS = new md5(reader.result);                                            $scope.md5Value = calcS.getMd5();

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to generate an MD5 file hash in JavaScript/Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14733374/how-to-generate-an-md5-file-hash-in-javascript-node-js)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I used the spark-md5.js from https://github.com/satazor/SparkMD5
It is awesome and pretty fast. This is the best solution if some one is trying to calculate the md5 of any uploaded file.

Answer (score 7):

I got it to work using `reader.readAsArrayBuffer()`:

```
$(inputElement).change(
    function () {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        
        reader.addEventListener(
            'load',
            function () {
                var wordArray = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(this.result);
                console.log(CryptoJS.MD5(wordArray));
            }
        );
        
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(this.files[0]);
    }
);
```

I had to add an extra dependency from CryptoJS: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.1.1/crypto-js.min.js

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/qaz7ygkv/).

Comment: When I try on jsFiddle it says "Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'FileReader': Please use the 'new' operator, this DOM object constructor cannot be called as a function." What would you suggest about this?

Comment: @Kubuntuer82 I have updated the jsFiddle link as required for this to continue working.