# Hash a entire folder instead of a single file

Tags: javascript

I'm using this code to hash a single file:

```
const fs = require('fs');
let result = digest(fs.readFileSync('/users/ispedro/desktop/Test.PDF'));
console.log('Huella Digital MD5: ' + result)
```

I am trying to achieve the same but of all the files included in a folder, so that the output would be something like this:

*The file (name of the file) generates the following MD5 hash: 175GKG3K6UZ6GAEE64BFKUN0MR*

I have tried with various codes but have not succeeded ... any ideas please?

Update:

What I want to do is that the script reads the contents of a folder on the desktop without having to compress it in zip, so that I can remove or put files and when executing the script it returns the MD5 hash of those that are currently inside. I have tried to copy part of the code from this link [npmjs.com/package/folder-hash](https://npmjs.com/package/folder-hash) which I think does exactly that but I can't get the script to work ...

Thank you very much to all.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to generate an MD5 file hash in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14733374/how-to-generate-an-md5-file-hash-in-javascript)

Comment: You'll have to read the contents of each file in the folder, concatenate them and then run `digest` on that.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv or maybe you can convert the entire folder into a compressed file like `zip` that would help reduce the problem i guess.

Comment: Sure, that's a solution too. I'm not sure how much entropy goes down because of compression though.

Comment: Thank you very much to all,

what I want to do is that the script reads the contents of a folder on the desktop without having to compress it in zip, so that I can remove or put files and when executing the script it returns the MD5 hash of those that are currently inside.

I have tried to copy part of the code from this link https://www.npmjs.com/package/folder-hash which I think does exactly that but I can't get the script to work ...