# Algorithm Needed: Predictable Randomized Tiles in Javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, random

Here is the function definition:

```
/**
 * @param {number} x The x-coordinate (can be positive or negative)
 * @param {number} y The y-coordinate (can be positive or negative)
 * @param {number} tileCount The number of available tiles
 * @return {number} The selected tile index
 */
 function getRandomTileIndex(x, y, tileCount) {
    // Fill in code here
 }
```

I could, for example, `return x * y % tileCount` but I want to introduce randomness. I could do `return Math.round(Math.random() * (tileCount-1))` but then that would return different tile indices every time.

I want this function to be deterministic, so when using the same input `(x, y, tileCount)` the same output will always occur. But I also want it to appear (as much as possible) to be random with an even distribution - the quality of the randomness does not have to be perfect.

The purpose for this random tile generator is for a game with a (nearly) infinite grid - user starts in the middle `(x,y) = (0,0)` and will move outwards in whatever direction he wants - I will only have a fixed number of background tiles for the "ground" - and I want it so that every time you load the game the world looks the same.

Comment: check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/424292/how-to-create-my-own-javascript-random-number-generator-that-i-can-also-set-the

Comment: Thanks Sam for that useful link - I think seedrandom is exactly what i needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to introduce "predictable randomness" then sounds like you want a hash.  Predictable randomness is an oxymoron as true randomness cannot be predictable, so we'll call it unknown but deterministic.

The algorithm looks like this:

1. use an algorithm (SHA-256, [md5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768268/how-to-calculate-md5-hash-of-a-file-using-javascript), etc) to hash some unique value
   for a given location `(x*Y)` sounds good to me (however this would
   introduce some symmetry -- `(1,1)` maps to the same as `(-1 -1)`
2. Use some attribute of the return value to return a tileCount
   number

   - maybe `sum(bits of hash) % tileCount`

To address the symmetry issue, you could add a large number to x and y so that the symmetry happens on an almost impossibly distant location. so:

```
hashVal = hash((x+53562345)*(y-235734093))
tileType = sum(hashVal bits) % tileCount
```

or you can use sum(hash(x)+hash(y)) that would eliminate the symmetry, but too many hash algorithms can get slow and clunky.

Comment: »Predictable randomness« could also refer to a PRNG.

Comment: @ajon I agree about the oxymoron. This is a good idea - I wonder though about the way to generate a unique number given x,y ... having symmetry `getRandomTileIndex(-1,-1,100) == getRandomTileIndex(1,1,100)` would be devastating to the effect I was trying to create.

Comment: @Joey, yes, I was just referring to the fact that this phrase doesn't work linguistically.  Granted in the industry prng are referred to as predictably random.

Comment: @codefactor See my addition to address the symmetry.

Comment: @ajon What do you think would happen with `hashVal = hash(x*53562345+y)` ?

Comment: That sounds like a great alternative.  good idea.

Comment: I think maybe instead I will use the answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/424292/how-to-create-my-own-javascript-random-number-generator-that-i-can-also-set-the using the x,y,tileCount as the seem to the random generator and then using `Math.random()` instead.

Comment: Summing two hashes would introduce a huge bias (for the same reason that 7 gets rolled more often than snake-eyes)

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft I had in my mind a small number of unique tiles maybe ~ 20, which would really minimize the bias, but your point is a great one.  I also hadn't looked at how few bits a lot of the hash algorithms are.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you using a function that creates the tiles dynamicaly and than saves them in an object.
So every time the function is called it will return the value from the created object.
For saving the object you could also use the HTML5 Local Storage for persistance if you want to create a HTML5 game.

---

A proposal would be:

```
/**
 * @param {number} x The x-coordinate (can be positive or negative)
 * @param {number} y The y-coordinate (can be positive or negative)
 * @param {number} tileCount The number of available tiles
 * @return {number} The selected tile index
 */
 var tiles = {};
 function getRandomTileIndex(x, y, tileCount) {
    var tile;
    if(tiles[x][y]) {
        tile = tiles[x][y];
    }
    else {
        tile = Math.round(Math.random() * (tileCount));
        tiles[x][y] = tile;
    }
    return tile;
 }
```

Comment: This is a good attempt - but like i said the world is (nearly) infinite - and I want it to be deterministic, so everyone sees the same world (regardless of which system, or if they have cleared cache, opened different browser, etc)

Comment: One other note: Users will be building stuff in the world, which other people will see, and likely they will build stuff according to what background they see - so it is important that everyone sees the same thing.

Comment: @codefactor So you want to create one big map, that will dynamically expend ?

Comment: Well I have a grid centered at (0,0) and when you move outwards I shift the grid to the left/right/up/down depending on direction. Stuff people build will have relative coordinates from the center - and I want to paint the background with these random tiles - but i want it to always be the same.