# How to know video is successfully uploaded or not?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a method which takes a file and upload it on given path.

Here is my service

```
public String fileUpload(MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
        log.debug("uploading video");
        File fileUpload = new File(file.getOriginalFilename());
        if (!file.isEmpty()) {

            InputStream inputStream = file.getInputStream();
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(
                    fileUploadPath + File.separator
                            + file.getOriginalFilename()));
            int numRead = 0;
            while ((numRead = inputStream.read(buf)) >= 0) {
                fileOutputStream.write(buf, 0, numRead);
            }
            inputStream.close();
            fileOutputStream.close();
}
else {
            return Constants.EMPTY_FILE;
        }
}
```

After uploading the file i have to save it information in my database.File size could be 1GB or 2GB.My problem is how would i know the file is fully uploaded or not.So that i can save it status uploaded successfully in my db.
Anyone please help me looking into this ?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can create a MD5 hash before uploading the file.  Take a look at this on creating MD5 hash with JavaScript via  [How to calculate md5 hash of a file using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768268/how-to-calculate-md5-hash-of-a-file-using-javascript).
2. And after the file is completely uploaded, you can use MessageDigest to create another MD5 hash to compare it again the one before the upload. (See example: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2013/06/how-to-generate-md5-checksum-for-files.html)