# Mechanisms for hashing a file in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, file, hash, binary

I am relatively new to JavaScript and I want to get the hash of a file, and would like to better understand the mechanism and code behind the process.

**So, what I need:** An MD5 or SHA-256 hash of an uploaded file to my website.

**My understanding of how this works:** A file is uploaded via an HTML `input` tag of type 'file', after which it is converted to a binary string, which is consequently hashed.

**What I have so far:** I have managed to get the hash of an input of type 'text', and also, somehow, the hash of an uploaded file, although the hash did not match with websites I looked at online, so I'm guessing it hashed some other details of the file, instead of the binary string.

**Question 1:** Am I correct in my understanding of how a file is hashed? Meaning, is it the binary string that gets hashed?

**Question 2:** What should my code look like to upload a file, hash it, and display the output?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Check out this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768268/how-to-calculate-md5-hash-of-a-file-using-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically yes, that's how it works.
But, to generate such hash, you don't need to do the conversion to string yourself. Instead, let the [SubtleCrypto API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/digest) handle it itself, and just pass an ArrayBuffer of your file.

```js
async function getHash(blob, algo = "SHA-256") {
  // convert your Blob to an ArrayBuffer
  // could also use a FileRedaer for this for browsers that don't support Response API
  const buf = await new Response(blob).arrayBuffer();
  const hash = await crypto.subtle.digest(algo, buf);
  let result = '';
  const view = new DataView(hash);
  for (let i = 0; i < hash.byteLength; i += 4) {
     result += view.getUint32(i).toString(16).padStart(2, '0');
  }
  return result;
}
inp.onchange = e => {
  getHash(inp.files[0]).then(console.log);
};
```

```html
<input id="inp" type="file">
```