# how to compare content of two word files ? my task is to compare word file downloaded using Protractor tool automation with existing file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, protractor

I am using Protractor Automation tool for UI automation. My task is to compare MS word file content downloaded through automation with another existing word file. Is there any library available to compare word file content in JS Or node.js, Protractor ?

Answer (score 0):

Normally you can just compare the MD5 hash of those two files. To generate the MD5 hash using javascript, you can refer to this question. [How to calculate md5 hash of a file using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768268/how-to-calculate-md5-hash-of-a-file-using-javascript)